# android webview use <img> load a image from sdcard

Tags: android, webview

i'm trying use webview to load a image from sdcard

i use this path :

file///sdcard/1.png

but i didn't see the picture.

is anything wrong?

Comment: try using    File file = new File(("/sdcard/"), "name.png");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to put your HTML and image file in the asset folder, and load the HTML file from there. Another solution is to use the method loadDataWithBaseURL() of WebView.